# XText grammar for markdown

Tags: markdown, xtext

I'm writing XText grammar for Markdown syntax. In markdown the h1 can be written with `#heading`.

So, Heading can match anything other than a newline character.

```
grammar org.example.domainmodel.DomainModel with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate domainModel "http://www.example.org/domainmodel/DomainModel"

DomainModel:
    (elements += Element)*
;

Element:
    Section1 | Section2
;

Section1:
    '#' name += HEADING '\n'
;

Section2:
    '##' name += HEADING '\n'
;

terminal HEADING: (('A'..'Z') | '_'| ('a'..'z') | ('0'..'9') | '-')* ;
```

But this gives error as :

`The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT`

Also, heading cannot have any special characters with this.

What is correct way of writing this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a new terminal rule HEADING, use terminal rule ID which is already defined:

```
Section1:
    '#' name = ID '\n'
;

Section2:
   '##' name = ID '\n'
;
```

Comment: Using ID will not allow the use special characters in Heading. I tried using `terminal HEADING: !('\n')* ;` as terminal rule. But it gives me error as `The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_ID,RULE_INT,RULE_ANY_OTHER`.

Comment: Delete common terminals from your grammar. The problem is in xtext first match wins. In your case HEADING could be matched with INT or ID terminal rule. 
So from first line just remove this 
    with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
also modify your HEADING terminal rule like this:
terminal HEADING: (('A'..'Z') | '_'| ('a'..'z') | ('0'..'9') | '-')(('A'..'Z') | '_'| ('a'..'z') | ('0'..'9') | '-')* ;